Данные в заказе 1С OData
Всем привет, столкнулся с проблемой получения данных в заказе при запросе через OData, данные получаю через эту ссылку http://localhost/mc/odata/standard.odata/Document_%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F?$format=json, но в ней нет информации о статусе заказа, типе оплаты и промокодах/сертификатах/промокодах, которые были применены к заказу. Подскажите пожалуйста, как их получить


Статус заказа:

В поле "СостояниеЗаказа": "47a25f01-402a-11ef-a2e3-7c70dbf47f44".
Оно указывает на идентификатор состояния заказа. Ссылка на тип состояния находится в "СостояниеЗаказа_Type": "StandardODATA.Catalog_СостоянияЗаказовПокупателей", что означает, что это связано с каталогом состояний заказов покупателей.


Тип оплаты:

В поле "ТипДенежныхСредств": "Безналичные".
Это указывает, что оплата производится безналичным расчётом.


Промокоды/сертификаты/скидки:

Скидки:

Поле "ПроцентСкидкиПоДисконтнойКарте": 0 и "СкидкиРассчитаны": true показывают, что скидки рассчитаны, но процент скидки по дисконтной карте равен нулю.
В массиве "Запасы" для каждого товара есть поля "ПроцентСкидкиНаценки": 0 и "СуммаСкидкиНаценки": 0, что указывает на отсутствие скидок или наценок.


Промокоды и сертификаты:

В данных не указаны явные поля для промокодов или сертификатов. Обычно, если бы такие данные присутствовали, они могли бы быть включены в поля с описанием скидок или добавлены в список дополнительных реквизитов или информацию по контрагенту.





Если нужны более детализированные данные, возможно, потребуется доступ к другим связанным записям или таблицам в системе, которые могут содержать расшифровку идентификаторов или дополнительные данные о скидках и промокодах.
